# When Will textFieldDidEndEditing:textField be called?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 UITextField in a ViewController. One brings up a UIDatePicker another brings up a KeyBoard(number pad). I then assign user inputs to two class variables, a NSDate variable and a NSNumber variable, in the following method.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField == self.datePickerTextField){
        //update xxtime
        self.xxTime = self.datePicker.date;
        NSLog(@"...%@",self.xxTime);
    }
     if (textField == self.numberTextField) {
        int val = [textField.text intValue];
        self.xxNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:val];
        NSLog(@"...%@",self.xxNumber);
    }

}
```

If I tap the datePickerTextField first then the numberTextField, this method won't get called after I finish typing in the numberTextField.

So my question is how do I make this method to get called?  Should I specify "resignFirstResponder" somewhere?

TIA

Answer (score 8):

It will invoke didEndEditing once another control gains focus

According to the [API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidEndEditing%3a),

> This method is called after the text field resigns its first responder
>   status.

So if you want didEndEditing to be invoked, you need to call

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Thank you! What will be a good place to call resignFirstResponder. Right now I am calling it when pressing a "save" button. But I wonder  if this is the best time/place to call it.

Answer (score 2):

Yo are right you need to specify resignFirstResponder

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {//Text Field Delegate
    if (textField == textField1) {
        [textField1 becomeFirstResponder];
    }else{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return TRUE; }
```

this can used with `textFieldDidEndEditing` also

Comment: Thank you! I don't have a return button so can't really use this. Trying to find a good place to call resignFirstResponder.

Answer (score 1):

Please check what iOS you are using. Remember that if you are using iOS 10, there is a method that is replacing the old textFieldDidEndEditing called `func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason)`